# sql database retrieves data, waiting approval, send back to original

Tags: php, sql

I am looking to have a testimonial page on a site, where it will allow for customers to submit their own testimonial. The issue is, not sending the data straight to the testimonial page, but to a separate "moderator page", to await approval. Every where I've looked seems to say make a SQL database. Is that the only solution or can I use php for this. Once this data is sent to the moderator page, I am wondering if it is possible to, once reviewed and approved, be able to press a submit button, and send the customer testimonial to the testimonial page? It's a lot I know, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't started anything yet. Wanted to know exactly which path I should take.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i cant comment, but you could make a confirmation field in the database that is set by default to "false" or whatever you want, then after review, update the field to "true" and when populating the testimonials, select from database where confirmation = "true"